# What tools can I use to keep track of dice in Dogs in the Vineyard played over Skype?

Tags: tools, dice, online-roleplaying, tool-recommendation, dogs-in-the-vineyard

My group is distributed across the globe, so we have to do all of our roleplaying online. We have a few different die-roller options that we use. However, none of them seem very well-suited to Dogs in the Vineyard, where the dice are rolled into pools at the beginning of conflict and then used up in pairs over the course of the conflict without re-rolling them.

What DitV-appropriate tools exist that would help us keep track of die rolls and share the results online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using the Dice Roller here:

http://catchyourhare.com/diceroller/

It allows you to share a password, and then roll and manipulate dice on a virtual tabletop.  This works really well for Dogs, because you all roll your piles of dice (each player using a different color) and then they can move them around as they are used in the conflict, and everyone will see the results.

It doesn't in any way restrict who can do what with which dice, but then, technically, neither do physical dice, so I think that's not really a problem.

Comment: I finally used this for a DitV game last winter, and it worked fairly well, with the exception of some occasional glitches - none of which were severe enough to stop us from sticking with it for the course of the game. Thanks for pointing it out!